# Darknet yolov3 prediction on Colab using js webcam code is very slow

Tags: javascript, python, google-colaboratory, yolo

I have already trained a yolov3 model, however, when predicting on my computer, it is incredibly slow. Even after adjusting the height and width, I still get less than 1 fps. I have turned to Colab to run the prediction, however, I have run in to several issues. The first being, to capture the webcam on Colab, it requires Javascript, which I am unfamiliar with at the moment. I have spent a little over a week messing around to get this to work. I have gotten to the point where it will predict on the webcam, however, it takes about 30 seconds to draw a box on the screen, and the boxes don't disappear.

Here is the script I found to run the webcam:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/vindruid/yolov3-in-colab/blob/master/yolov3_streaming_webcam.ipynb#scrollTo=A0ZgJiQBskDt

And here is some code that I wrote that combines the webcam code and detection code:

```
import base64
import html
import io
import time

from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

def start_input():          #webcam
  js = Javascript('''
    var video;
    var div = null;
    var stream;
    var captureCanvas;
    var imgElement;
    var labelElement;
    
    var pendingResolve = null;
    var shutdown = false;
    
    function removeDom() {
       stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
       video.remove();
       div.remove();
       video = null;
       div = null;
       stream = null;
       imgElement = null;
       captureCanvas = null;
       labelElement = null;
    }
    
    function onAnimationFrame() {
      if (!shutdown) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
      }
      if (pendingResolve) {
        var result = "";
        if (!shutdown) {
          captureCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 512, 512);
          result = captureCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8)
        }
        var lp = pendingResolve;
        pendingResolve = null;
        lp(result);
      }
    }
    
    async function createDom() {
      if (div !== null) {
        return stream;
      }

      div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.border = '2px solid black';
      div.style.padding = '3px';
      div.style.width = '100%';
      div.style.maxWidth = '600px';
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      
      const modelOut = document.createElement('div');
      modelOut.innerHTML = "<span>Status:</span>";
      labelElement = document.createElement('span');
      labelElement.innerText = 'No data';
      labelElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      modelOut.appendChild(labelElement);
      div.appendChild(modelOut);
           
      video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      video.width = div.clientWidth - 6;
      video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
      video.onclick = () => { shutdown = true; };
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
          {video: { facingMode: "environment"}});
      div.appendChild(video);

      imgElement = document.createElement('img');
      imgElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      imgElement.style.zIndex = 1;
      imgElement.onclick = () => { shutdown = true; };
      div.appendChild(imgElement);
      
      const instruction = document.createElement('div');
      instruction.innerHTML = 
          '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">' +
          'When finished, click here or on the video to stop this demo</span>';
      div.appendChild(instruction);
      instruction.onclick = () => { shutdown = true; };
      
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      captureCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      captureCanvas.width = 512; //video.videoWidth;
      captureCanvas.height = 512; //video.videoHeight;
      window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
      
      return stream;
    }
    async function takePhoto(label, imgData) {
      if (shutdown) {
        removeDom();
        shutdown = false;
        return '';
      }

      var preCreate = Date.now();
      stream = await createDom();
      
      var preShow = Date.now();
      if (label != "") {
        labelElement.innerHTML = label;
      }
            
      if (imgData != "") {
        var videoRect = video.getClientRects()[0];
        imgElement.style.top = videoRect.top + "px";
        imgElement.style.left = videoRect.left + "px";
        imgElement.style.width = videoRect.width + "px";
        imgElement.style.height = videoRect.height + "px";
        imgElement.src = imgData;
      }
      
      var preCapture = Date.now();
      var result = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pendingResolve = resolve;
      });
      shutdown = false;
      
      return {'create': preShow - preCreate, 
              'show': preCapture - preShow, 
              'capture': Date.now() - preCapture,
              'img': result};
    }
    ''')

  display(js)
  
def take_photo(label, img_data):
  data = eval_js('takePhoto("{}", "{}")'.format(label, img_data))
  return data




import cv2            
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sys import platform


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--img-size', type=int, default=416, help='inference size (pixels)')
opt = parser.parse_args(args = [])




weights = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/yolov3_recent/yolov3_training_2000.weights'

from model import *
from models import * 
from utils.datasets import *
from utils.utils import *

    
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights,'/content/Weightlifting_project/yolov3_cfg')
classes = []
with open("/content/Weightlifting_project/classes.txt", "r") as f:
  classes = f.read().splitlines()
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

boxes = []
confidences = []
class_ids = []
box = []
knee_loc = []
hip_loc = []
foot_loc = []
knee_loc_2 = []
hip_loc_2 = []
foot_loc_2 = []
box_2 = []











def js_reply_to_image(js_reply):
    """
    input: 
          js_reply: JavaScript object, contain image from webcam

    output: 
          image_array: image array RGB size 512 x 512 from webcam
    """
    jpeg_bytes = base64.b64decode(js_reply['img'].split(',')[1])
    image_PIL = Image.open(io.BytesIO(jpeg_bytes))
    image_array = np.array(image_PIL)

    return image_array

def get_drawing_array(image_array): 
    """
    input: 
          image_array: image array RGB size 512 x 512 from webcam

    output: 
          drawing_array: image RGBA size 512 x 512 only contain bounding box and text, 
                              channel A value = 255 if the pixel contains drawing properties (lines, text) 
                              else channel A value = 0
    """
    drawing_array = np.zeros([512,512,4], dtype=np.uint8)  
    img = letterbox(image_array, new_shape=opt.img_size)[0]
    
    #img = image_array.transpose(2, 0, 1)
    #img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

    #img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(device)
    #img = img.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
    #img /= 255.0  # (0 - 255) to (0.0 - 1.0)
    #if img.ndimension() == 3:
        #img = img.unsqueeze(0)
   
    
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (512, 512), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)



    outputs(layerOutputs,480,480,boxes,confidences,class_ids,box,box_2)
    
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.3)

    if indexes is not None:
      plot(indexes,boxes,classes,class_ids,confidences,colors,drawing_array,font)
    

    drawing_array[:,:,3] = (drawing_array.max(axis = 2) > 0 ).astype(int) * 255
    return drawing_array

def drawing_array_to_bytes(drawing_array):
    """
    input: 
          drawing_array: image RGBA size 512 x 512 
                              contain bounding box and text from yolo prediction, 
                              channel A value = 255 if the pixel contains drawing properties (lines, text) 
                              else channel A value = 0

    output: 
          drawing_bytes: string, encoded from drawing_array
    """

    drawing_PIL = Image.fromarray(drawing_array, 'RGB')
    iobuf = io.BytesIO()
    drawing_PIL.save(iobuf, format='png')
    drawing_bytes = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format((str(base64.b64encode(iobuf.getvalue()), 'utf-8')))
    return drawing_bytes

start_input()
label_html = 'Capturing...'
img_data = ''
count = 0 
while True:
    js_reply = take_photo(label_html, img_data)
    if not js_reply:
        break

    image = js_reply_to_image(js_reply)
    drawing_array = get_drawing_array(image) 
    drawing_bytes = drawing_array_to_bytes(drawing_array)
    img_data = drawing_bytes
```

If someone could take a look to see why its so slow and if I'm doing something wrong(I'm certain I am), that would be awesome!